# Can I flow_from_dataframe if my labels are also filepaths?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train an image reconstruction network, that I would train like this:

```
vae.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=10, batch_size=1)
```

where `X_train` is a NumPy array of the training images.

However, I want to use a generator because otherwise, I run out of memory. I have tried to use `flow_from_dataframe`, where I have all the file paths of the images stored (they are across multiple folders).

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
                                   dataframe=df,
                                   x_col="filepath",
                                   y_col="filepath")
```

The issue is this function inputs `x_col` (file path) and `y_col`(label). Since my loss function is based on reconstruction error, my label should be the same image itself. Is there a way to do this with this function or with another kind of generator?

Answer (score 1):

For autoencoders, you can set `class_mode=input`, and then you don't have to set `y_col`.

So try this:

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
                                   dataframe=df,
                                   x_col="filepath",
                                   class_mode="input")
```